# Is there a way for a css3 class to follow the mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am quite new to CSS3 and JavaScript and I am digging for few days this subject.
I want to mask a photo with an image. And I want to the mask to follow the mouse pointer.
I read that masking is done with the class attribute mask or mask-image, followed by the url of an image.
Is there a way to reposition this mask when the mouse move?

Comment: `I read that masking is done with the class attribute mask or mask-image, followed by the url of an image.`... That's not part of any standard, but may be one way to do it..

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use JavaScript to listen to the `mousemove` event:

Something like this:

```
document.getElementById('myVerySpecificContainer').addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  // reposition whatever with the event coordinates (clientX, clientY, screenX, screenY)
}
```

When you're done, `removeEventListener` because it's a very expensive event.

Available event properties can be found here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove

Answer (score 0):

set initial style: (using clipping in this case)

```
  #pic {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px, 100px, 100px, 0px);
  }
```

then set some js to update the style on mouse move

```
<img id='pic' src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/clip1a.png" width="568">
    <script>
      document.body.onmousemove= function(e){
        document.getElementById("pic").style.clip = "rect("+(e.clientY-50)+"px "+(e.clientX+50)+"px "+(e.clientY+50)+"px "+(e.clientX-50)+"px)";
      }
    </script>
```

working plunkr sample
http://plnkr.co/edit/B8vKjIIFYp2oxiX6o8uI?p=preview

Comment: Great, thanks!  I will try with a mask rather than a clip:  I did the website http://www.obscures.net in flash long time ago, I want to do it again in tablet compliant technologies.  I would need to mask with a shape which has a circular gradient, either a svg with filters, or an image.

Comment: So now for the clipping. clip-path and clip don't work.  Why did they kill flash again?